# Why can't Observable.interval() unsubscribe?

Tags: android, android-fragments, rx-java

I created a `viewpager` and the `fragment` has a `RecyclerView` & `viewholder`.

```
@Override
public void bindModel(GankInfo item) {
   super.bindModel(item);
   picViewPager.setOnTouchListener(((v, event) -> {
       switch (event.getAction()){
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
               stopPlay();
               break;
           }
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
               startPlay();
               break;
           }
        }
        return false;
   }));
}

@Override
public void onAttach() {
   super.onAttach();
   startPlay();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
   super.onDetach();
   stopPlay();
}

private void stopPlay(){
    subscription.unsubscribe();
}

private void startPlay(){
    subscription =
            Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                      .subscribe(aLong -> {
                             int currentPosition = picViewPager.getCurrentItem();
                             currentPosition++; 
                             picViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition==picViewPager.getAdapter().getCount()?0:currentPosition);
             });
}
```

I used `Leakcanary` to find the memory leak with the fragment. When I swipe the viewpager the fragment will leak memory. I call this stop with the `adapter.onViewDetachedFromWindow` And leakcanary will notify always many times. I try to google some ways to solve my problem but those fail to work. Here:

- [CompositeSubscription.unsubscribe](http://www.paul-woitaschek.de/blog/when-to-use-composite-subscription-unsubscribe/)
- [Obseravle.interval().onTerminateDetach()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4657)

[image: the leakcanary]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why Observable.interval() can not unsubscribe

if accidentally you call `startPlay` twice, you override the previous Subscription, and hence you are leaking it. To overcome it you could subscribe only if the Subscription is unsubscribed. E.g.

```
Subscription subscription = Subscriptions.unsubscribed();

private void startPlay(){
   if (subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
       subscription =
               Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                      .subscribe(aLong -> {
                             int currentPosition = picViewPager.getCurrentItem();
                             currentPosition++; 
                             picViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition==picViewPager.getAdapter().getCount()?0:currentPosition);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: but wht use `CompositeSubscription` not work. `subscriprion.add()`